# Fabric JS how to set border radius on bounding box of selected objects

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Is it possible to change the border radius of a bounding box of a selected item? I have read through the documentation of the possible attributes that can be attributed to an object and haven't found anything that specifies the changing of the border radius of an object's bounding box. Is there perhaps an solution through CSS this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a drop-in replacement for the `fabric.Object.prototype.drawBorders` method that handles the drawing of selection borders. I've extended it to use the property `selectionRadius` to determine the amount of border radius to use in the selection box.

[image]

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  width: 150,
  height: 100,
  left: 25,
  top: 25,
  fill: 'lightgreen',
  strokeWidth: 0,
  padding: 20,
  selectionRadius: 20,
  borderColor: 'red'
}));

fabric.Object.prototype.drawBorders = function(ctx, styleOverride) {
  styleOverride = styleOverride || {};
  var wh = this._calculateCurrentDimensions(),
    strokeWidth = this.borderScaleFactor,
    width = wh.x + strokeWidth,
    height = wh.y + strokeWidth,
    hasControls = typeof styleOverride.hasControls !== 'undefined' ?
    styleOverride.hasControls : this.hasControls,
    shouldStroke = false;

  ctx.save();
  ctx.strokeStyle = styleOverride.borderColor || this.borderColor;
  this._setLineDash(ctx, styleOverride.borderDashArray || this.borderDashArray, null);

  //start custom draw method with rounded corners
  var rx = this.selectionRadius ? Math.min(this.selectionRadius, width / 2) : 0,
    ry = this.selectionRadius ? Math.min(this.selectionRadius, height / 2) : 0,
    w = width,
    h = height,
    x = -width / 2,
    y = -height / 2,
    isRounded = rx !== 0 || ry !== 0,
    /* "magic number" for bezier approximations of arcs */
    k = 1 - 0.5522847498;
  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.moveTo(x + rx, y);

  ctx.lineTo(x + w - rx, y);
  isRounded && ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + w - k * rx, y, x + w, y + k * ry, x + w, y + ry);

  ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h - ry);
  isRounded && ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + w, y + h - k * ry, x + w - k * rx, y + h, x + w - rx, y + h);

  ctx.lineTo(x + rx, y + h);
  isRounded && ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + k * rx, y + h, x, y + h - k * ry, x, y + h - ry);

  ctx.lineTo(x, y + ry);
  isRounded && ctx.bezierCurveTo(x, y + k * ry, x + k * rx, y, x + rx, y);

  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  //end custom draw method with rounded corners


  if (hasControls) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    this.forEachControl(function(control, key, fabricObject) {
      // in this moment, the ctx is centered on the object.
      // width and height of the above function are the size of the bbox.
      if (control.withConnection && control.getVisibility(fabricObject, key)) {
        // reset movement for each control
        shouldStroke = true;
        ctx.moveTo(control.x * width, control.y * height);
        ctx.lineTo(
          control.x * width + control.offsetX,
          control.y * height + control.offsetY
        );
      }
    });
    if (shouldStroke) {
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
  ctx.restore();
  return this;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey Melchiar, thanks for the answer, I will check it out tomorrow to see if it worked.